# PHP: Avoid undefined index?

Tags: php

Every time a POST value is not equal to the list of values set in an array will return: Undefined Index error, I made an if statement but is not working.

Here's the if statement:

```
 if ($products[$_POST['product']] == $_POST['product']) {
do everything;}
else {
echo "This item is not available";
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Seen the current situation avoiding the warning wont help much because I'm dealing with several factors, for example a list of items in a Shopping Cart, if the invalid product is not removed, it will be added to the shopping list session.

This is the full script:

```
<?php

session_start();

//Getting the list
 $_SESSION['list'] = isset($_SESSION['list']) ? $_SESSION['list'] : array();    

 //stock    
 $products = array(      
     'Pineaple' => 500, 'Banana' => 50, 'Mango' => 150,       
     'Milk' => 500, 'Coffe' => 1200, 'Butter' => 300,      
     'Bread' => 450, 'Juice' => 780, 'Peanuts' => 800,      
     'Yogurt' => 450, 'Beer' => 550, 'Wine' => 2500,    
 );    

if( isset($_POST['product']) ){


     //Saving the stuff    
     $new_item = array(      
         'item' => $_POST['product'],       
         'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],     
         'code' => $_POST['code'],      
         'price' => $products[$_POST['product']] * $_POST['quantity'],    

     );



    $new_product = true;    
    foreach($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $item) {      
        if ($item['item'] == $new_item['item']) {        
        $_SESSION['list'][$key]['quantity'] += $new_item['quantity'];        
        $_SESSION['list'][$key]['price'] = $products[$new_item['item']] * $new_item['quantity'];        
        $new_product = false;
        }    
    }   

    if ($new_product) {      
        $_SESSION['list'][] = $new_item;        
    }    

    /*if ($new_item['item'] != $products[$new_item['item']]) {
        echo "This item is not available";}*/

    //listing    
    echo  "<b>SHOPPING LIST</b></br>";    
    foreach($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $item) {       
        echo 'Product .'. $key. ' '. $item['item'], ' ', $item['quantity'], ' units: ', $item['price']. '<br />';    
        }

}

else {
echo "This item is not available";
}

echo "</br> <a href='index.html'>Return to index</a> </br>";

//Printing session
var_dump($_SESSION);

session_destroy();

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Use if( isset($yourvariable ) ) to avoide index error in php

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your code. It looks like your array has the same key and value, so:

```
$products['saucepan'] = 'saucepan'
```

Perhaps you are trying to do this, which will check whether the product exists in the products array:

```
if(isset($_POST['product']) && array_key_exists($_POST['product'], $products))
{
  // do stuff
}
else
{
  echo "This item is not available";
}
```

Comment: +1 for `array_key_exists`, `isset`'s more specific, more useful big brother.

Answer (score 33):

With PHP 7, the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) can be used to deal with optional request variables. You can change your `$_POST['product']` reference to `$_POST['product'] ?? null` which will resolve to null (rather than throwing the warning) if 'product' is not a valid key in the post array. If you wanted to check both the $_POST and $_GET arrays for a value, you would use `$_POST['product'] ?? $_GET['product'] ?? null`.

Comment: Upvote for referencing the new(ish) operator. It's more declarative and shorter.

Comment: This should be the best answer, it's definitively faster to type and the answer author highlighted its use in this context that's not so obvious.

Comment: Yes, I love this.

Answer (score 12):

```
@$_POST['product']
```

(with an **@**) will return the same thing as :

```
$product = (isset($_POST['product'])) ? $_POST['product'] : null;
```

**Shorter is sweeter !!** 4 times less code ! Easier to read and understand.

> The @ symbol is the error control operator (AKA the "silence" or
>   "shut-up" operator). It makes PHP suppress any error messages (notice,
>   warning, fatal, etc.).

But beware not to use @ for any other thing, as it would make your code so much harder to debug!

(this will answer your question before the edit)

Comment: This doesn’t seem like a good answer. Silencing errors is never the right approach.

Comment: @EvanHendler checking for isset first then evaluing the value is no better than the ' @ ' !  But for other things, silencing errors isn't a great thing to do - that is especially why I warn people about it in the answer.

Comment: I've gotta go with Cedric on this one, the `@` operator has a very limited use, up til now I have used it only on `@session_start()` (which throws an annoying notice for apparently no functional reason), the succinctness of `$var = @$_POST['var']` is way too nice to throw it in the 'never suppress errors' basket.

Comment: @EvanHendler Silencing errors is never right approach, but silencing notices is a different story. Notices might help with finding cause of follow-up error but if my code is fine with getting null instead of expected value this mandatory array_key_exists() might pollute code in PHP quite extensively making it harder to comprehend.

Comment: man! you just made my day, i've been looking for this thing for a log time.

Comment: STRONGLY agree with @EvanHendler. Silencing errors/notices is never the correct approach. Programming is not about reducing lines of code or line length. Clean code is about being clear. Code == Communication. The (slightly) longer version that uses `isset` clearly communicates what you're doing, what you're expecting and why. The error suppression version communicates nothing and may get in the way of debugging.

Answer (score 9):

You should first check to see if $_POST['product'] is set with [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), like:

```
if( isset($_POST['product']) ){
    // Do something with $_POST['product']
}
```

That should suppress the warning.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try

```
$product = (isset($_POST['product'])) ? $_POST['product'] : null;
```

This will set $product to the $_POST value if it exists, or to null if not.
Then you could try

```
if ($product) {
  do_something();
}
```

or access your array with

```
$products[$product];
```

I feel this way it makes your code that little bit easier on the eyes..

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `??` to set set a default value if your value is not set.

`$_POST['product'] ?? "No product";`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most elegant and readable way of doing it, it is not a one-liner but readable nevertheless.

```
$product = $_POST['product'] ?? null;
if(empty($product)){
 // $product was not set in the request. Interrupt, throw error or deal with it here
}

// At this point $product is set, continue as normal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($products[$_POST['product']]) && $products[$_POST['product']] == $_POST['product'])
```

the isset() function will help you avoid the warning

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($products[$_POST['product']) && $products[$_POST['product'] != "")
```

Note that a vriable can be empty but also "set" so the what comes after the && is necessary.

Comment: You could use `if(empty($products[$_POST['product']))` which will also check whether the value is null or 0.

Comment: @Blowski : if index 0 valid for $product then?

Comment: @Gaurav Fair point. I would check the $_POST['product'] first and then use `array_key_exists()` as in my answer.

Comment: Thanks fatnjazzy, however since I'm using a SESSION the invalid value will be re-used, thus stopping the event would be much more effective, can you check for a minute my recently EDITED question?

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether the index 'product' is defined in the same if statement ..

```
if (isset($_POST['product']) && $products[$_POST['product']] == $_POST['product']) {
    do everything;
}
else {
    echo "This item is not available";
}
```